# jQuery Ajax call returns HTML, but HTML is not placed in document

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to create an Ajax call which is triggered when a Select box changes. It loads another PHP function using

`$('.selectbox').load("/path/to/script.php?x=" + x + "&y=" + y);`

This call is successfull since I can see in Firebug that the call returns the HTML from the PHP (which are in fact `<option>` tags). However, this HTML is not placed into the `.selectbox` element. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you include the HTML for the `.selectbox` element?

Comment: `<select name="foo" class="selectbox">
<option value=""></option>
</select>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems correct. Make sure you get the proper HTML markup to be inserted into `<select>`. The expected response is `<option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option>`

Or Try using other Ajax methods like [$.get](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) or [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/TVZbS/

Comment: Thanks, the `$.get` function works perfectly. I guess this is a better way to perform AJAX requests.

Answer (score 0):

What might be happening is that you are requesting URL that results in redirect, and that has no content. Maybe a "/" is added somewhere or something like that... Make sure that generated URL exactly matches what you would see in browsers address bar.

Comment: I doubt that: "This call is successfull since I can see in Firebug that the call returns the HTML from the PHP"

Comment: Indeed the call to the script is successfull.